# Xamarion IOS, acerca de reproducción de audio por librería Audiotoolbox

Tags: xamarin.forms

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Xamarín para IOS, el objetivo es reproducir un audio entrante de un buffer que lo obtengo vía UDP, al parecer la clase OutputAudioQueue se encarga de reproduccir el Audio, el problema es el cómo agregar los datos del buffer entrante de tipo byte[] y/o cómo se podría convertir de byte[] a un objeto de tipo Audiobuffer, que ese la clase con la cual se puede realizar el flujo de datos???

Alguna idea??
Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir tu código para ver como se te puede ayudar y trabajar así sobre el mismo? De igual manera te invito a pasarte por https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para ver como elaborar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.